# C++ move all files from one directory to another

Tags: c++, linux, file

I have a problem moving data from one directory to another.
I want to do as below (bash) but in C++:

```sh
mv /testdir/* /testdest/
```

So it should basically move all files located in `/testdir` to `/testdest`.
I've already tried `rename` in C++ but it does not actually move data, it just renames directories.

My current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  rename (argv[1], argv[2])
}
```

I am executing this as below:

```sh
./static-mv /testdir/ /testdest/
```

Effect of this is rename `/testdir/` to `/testdest/` (with its content).
After this, `/testdir/` is no longer available which is not the expected result.

Comment: You'll have to write a loop, it's not a single operation in bash either.

Comment: [`mv`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/mv.c) is non-trivial because it handles a ton of options. I would recommend looking into [`std::filesystem::rename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) and the [`directory_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

Comment: Hint:  `mv /testdir/* /testdest/`  expands to the arguments `mv` `/testdir/A` `testdir\B` `testdir\C` `testdest`

Comment: So .... if I want to move all files I need to actually do this one by one? (in loop?)

Comment: `mv` just changes directory entries if the files are in the same filesystem, but has to move data if it crosses a boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// static-mv.cpp
#include<experimental/filesystem>
#include<cassert>
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    assert(argc >= 3);
    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
    for(fs::path p : fs::directory_iterator(argv[1])){
        std::cout << p << " -> " << argv[2]/p.filename() << std::endl;
        fs::rename(p, argv[2]/p.filename());
    }
}
```

---

`$ c++ -std=c++11 static-mv.cpp -o static-mv -lstdc++fs`

`$ mkdir dir1; cd dir1; touch file.a; touch file.b; cd ..; ls dir1/`

```
file.a  file.b
```

`$ mkdir dir2;`

`$ ./static-mv dir1 dir2`

```
"dir1/file.a" -> "dir2/file.a"
"dir1/file.b" -> "dir2/file.b"
```

`$ ls dir2/`

```
file.a  file.b
```

`$ success!`

```
bash: success!: command not found...
```

Comment: <experimental/filesystem> is deprecated as of C++17, Gives below error 
`#ifndef _SILENCE_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATION_WARNING
#error The <experimental/filesystem> header providing std::experimental::filesystem is deprecated by Microsoft \
and will be REMOVED. It is superseded by the C++17 <filesystem> header providing std::filesystem. \
You can define _SILENCE_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATION_WARNING to acknowledge that you have received this warning.
#endif // _SILENCE_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATION_WARNING`

Comment: @ShubhamJain, care to update the answer? Besides you are compiling with Microsoft, which it is unlikely to apply to this linux question (linux tag was used).

Answer (score 1):

You might use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) to collect all the paths, and then loop on [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) & [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html). `nftw` uses [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), `closedir`, [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (which you might directly use).

With a recent C++17 implementation you might use [`<filesystem>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

If some *other* process is writing into subdirectories, you could be in trouble (as `mv` probably is).

Perhaps running `/bin/mv` (that file path is standardized by POSIX) in another process could be simpler.

There could be issues if `/testdir`and `/testdest` are in *different* file systems (and mount points), since [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) works only in one file system. `mv` knows how to handle that (in that case, it copy files before deleting the source). Also, some of the sub-directories of `/testdir` could be mount points, etc..

If both `/testdir/` and `/testdest/` are in the same file system and there is no mount points under `/testdir`, you could just loop with `opendir`, `readdir`, `closedir`, skip the `.` and `..` entries, construct for each directory entry the corresponding full source and destination paths, and use `rename` on these.

Of course, `mv` is free software, in [GNU `coreutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), and you might study its source code (it is less simple that what you might believe, since it handles corner cases). You could also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand which [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) are involved by some `mv` command or process.

Answer (score 0):

```
void move(char const *sorc, char const *dst, bool createRoot = true) {
    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

    if (createRoot)
        fs::create_directory(dst);

    for(fs::path p: fs::directory_iterator(sorc)){
        fs::path destFile = dst/p.filename();

        if (fs::is_directory(p)) {
            fs::create_directory(destFile);
            move(p.string().c_str(), destFile.string().c_str(), false);
        } else {
            //std::cout << "updated " << p.string().c_str() << std::endl;
            fs::rename(p, destFile);
        }
    }
}
```